# Facebood SDK returns HTTP/2 in header

Tags: php, regex, facebook

I am using facebook SDK for authenticating user and getting the list of facebook pages. The SDK works well on my dev server but crashes on production server. On debugging I found out that the header response is different on dev and production server.

The header response coming on dev server is HTTP/1.1 and on production server it is HTTP/2 which breaks the regular expression and the SDK.

There is a file in SDK called

```
/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Http/GraphRawResponse.php
```

and fucntion is:

```
public function setHttpResponseCodeFromHeader($rawResponseHeader)
    {
        preg_match('|HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)\s+.*|', $rawResponseHeader, $match);

        $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1];
    }
```

and according to the regular expression there must be a decimal number with decimal point but on production it is just 2 which is breaking it.

My question: Is it something related to my server configuration on production or facebook is sending those headers. If facebook is sending the headers then why is it behaving differently as I have the same SDK version.
If it is some server issue then how to fix it?

Comment: Update the SDK to a current version - the code of that method has been modified, https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/23928048b39e649abecd658f01a25bc833327b57/src/Facebook/Http/GraphRawResponse.php#L105

Comment: It worked like a charm, please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the SDK to a current version - the code of that method has been modified, presumably to take HTTP/2 into account.

https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/23928048b39e649abecd658f01a25bc833327b57/src/Facebook/Http/GraphRawResponse.php#L105

```
public function setHttpResponseCodeFromHeader($rawResponseHeader)
{
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2
    list($version, $status, $reason) = array_pad(explode(' ', $rawResponseHeader, 3), 3, null);
    $this->httpResponseCode = (int) $status;
}
```